# Use User-Defined build settings in custom .plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, google-signin

I have different build configurations (Debug, Stage, Prod) defined for my app and I use **User-Defined** build settings:

[image]

to set up Facebook login and other stuff in `Info.plist` file:

[image]

In this scenario the `$(USER_DEFINED_SETTINGS)` notation **does** work.

When I tried to set up **Google SignIn**, which requires using additional `.plist` file (`GoogleService-Info.plist`), and I used **User-Defined** settings in the same way I do in the `Info.plist` file, it doesn't work.

How can I use **User-Defined** settings in custom `.plist` files? If I can't, how can I workaround this?

Comment: Check **xcconfig** functional. Maybe it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328837/change-user-defined-variable-from-fastlane

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's **NOT** possible to use **User-Defined** settings in **custom** .plist file.

**BUT** you can copy your custom .plist file to the right place when building the app:

1. Create a new folder (for example: `Resources/GoogleServiceInfoPlists`).
2. Copy there all .plist files for build configuration. For example:
3. `GoogleService-Info-Debug.plist`
4. `GoogleService-Info-Stage.plist`
5. `GoogleService-Info-Prod.plist`
6. Add new `Run Script Phase` - Xcode: *Target-->Build Phases-->"+" button* (top left corner).
7. Use the script below to copy (replace) .plist file for given build configuration to the project directory:

   ```
   cp "${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME}/Resources/GoogleServiceInfoPlists/GoogleService-Info-$CONFIGURATION.plist" "${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
   ```
8. Under Output Files, you should possibly also enter the target file in order to ensure the next phase begins only if the file was actually copied.

   ```
   "${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
   ```
9. Important: move newly added script **before** `Copy Bundle Resources` phase, or it will use the default file, ignoring replaced file.

**Used variables/paths:**

`${SRCROOT}` - predefined, it points to your project location.

`${PRODUCT_NAME}` - predefined, product name.

`$CONFIGURATION` - predefined, it's your build configuration. By default, it is: `Debug`, `Release`. In my case: `Debug`, `Stage`, `Prod`. You can change build configurations in Xcode: *Project* (not Target!)-->*Info*.

**Note:**

`GoogleService-Info.plist` file **must** be added to the Xcode project resources (*Build Phases-->Copy Bundle Resource*s) while `Resources/GoogleServiceInfoPlists/GoogleService-Info-*` files not necessarily.

If the above doesn't work try clicking in your disired .plist file > File Inspector > Target Membership > Check your main project so it can be bundled together in final output.

Comment: +1 Although I don't like the solution itself, I cannot find any other way to achieve it. Google should provide at least the way to change the tracking identifier through the API (and not modify the .plist ourselves).

Comment: @GoRoS I agree it's not the best solution I can imagine, but unfortunately, it's the only way I could achieve that after spending a lot of time trying to solve this nicely.

Comment: I think you can use ${USER_DEFINED_SETTINGS} not in a custom plist, but in your project`s Info.plist, but I haven´t tried it yet.

Comment: Sure, but Google sign-in requires separate (custom) .plist file.

Comment: This is minor but is there a way to have the script run before the app starts? It doesn't seem to copy the file until after the app launches and you can test this by changing the settings and running. The only way to make sure is to Build first, then run.

Comment: I applied this solution and came across the following issue. I do see the file getting copied into my main directory, however, I think the file didn't get linked with my Xcode project so it still resulted in "missing GoogleService-Info.plist file". Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: @howly I have 4 files in my repository `GoogleService-Info.plist` and these 3 mentioned in my answer. `GoogleService-Info.plist` is **replaced** (not just copied) by 1 of these, so Xcode doesn't complain about it.

Comment: @pixelfreak, have you tried clicking and dragging the build phases to ensure the copying takes place before the files are linked?

Comment: @howly beside adding a 'Run Script Phase' you have click in your custom .plist file > File Inspector > Target Membership to your project so it can be bundled together in final output

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new folder (for example: `GoogleServiceInfoPlists`).
2. Copy there all `.plist` files for each Configuration

for example:

```
GoogleService-Info-Debug.plist, 
GoogleService-Info-Alpha.plist,
GoogleService-Info-Beta.plist,
GoogleService-Info-Release.plist
```

3. Add new `Run Script Phase` at last (Xcode: Target -> Build Phases -> "+" button).
4. Use script below to copy `.plist` file for given environment to the build directory.

script:

```
RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME}/GoogleServiceInfoPlists/GoogleService-Info-$CONFIGURATION.plist

BUILD_APP_DIR=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app

echo "Copying ${RESOURCE_PATH} to ${BUILD_APP_DIR}"
cp "${RESOURCE_PATH}" "${BUILD_APP_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

PS: You do not need to add the file to project. Just create a new folder in the main directory.

[image]

Comment: @Cleversou I get the issue `Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.` Are you using the new build settings?

Comment: @smj2393  try clicking in your disired .plist file > File Inspector > Target Membership > Check your main project so it can be bundled together in final output.

Answer (score 2):

I put two files with the (same) name *GoogleService-Info.plist* into my project.

[image]

One is at the root and one is in a folder called 'staging', so as to avoid a naming conflict in the file system.

[image: Include the plist in only one project each]

Including one in one target and the other in another makes it so that each target has a unique plist file with the correct name.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's a better solution.

You can replace Env variables(including User-Defined) manually using [my swift script](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/3524c8bd8cea9419ced527504c5d5b21).

It takes two arguments: input and output paths. Goes through all input plist values recursively (if you need to can add dict keys to be processed too), and replaces all Env variables it founds. And writes to output path.

This is how you use it in your `Run script phase`:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun --sdk macosx swift "${PROJECT_DIR}/scripts/replacePlistEnvironmentVariables.swift"  "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```